# After Ubuntu 16.04 installation can't install almost anything

Tags: package-management, dependencies, skype, steam, 32-bit

I fresh installed Ubuntu 16.04 to my laptop recently, and since then I can't install lots of things. I know there is a bug in the Software Center, but the problem is not limited to that specific problem.

I can't install Steam (always says missing dependencies, which I also can't install), Skype (again dependencies), VLC, Dropbox (breaks some packages) etc.

Since the problem with Skype and Steam is relevant to i386, and I could install them when I was using 14.04, I fresh installed 14.04. This time I couldn't install Skype nor Steam. So I'm back to 16.04 and can't find a way to fix those missing dependencies.

I used `apt-get -f install`, `aptitude -f install`, manually downloading and installing those packages, and even their dependent packages, but every time there is a missing dependency.  Now I don't have my basic apps. Any idea what's causing this?

I tried to install Steam again yesterday, because Ubuntu software and some other things updated, and when it tried to install its dependencies again it didn't work. And when I do `sudo apt-get -f install` it gives this:

> Paket listeleri okunuyor... Bitti
>   Bağımlılık ağacı oluşturuluyor
>   Durum bilgisi okunuyor... Bitti
>   Bağımlılıklar düzeltiliyor... Tamamlandı
>   Aşağıdaki ek paketler kurulacak:
>     libc6:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386
>   Önerilen paketler:
>     glibc-doc:i386 locales:i386
>   Aşağıdaki YENİ paketler kurulacak:
>     libc6:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386
>   0 paket yükseltilecek, 2 yeni paket kurulacak, 0 paket kaldırılacak ve 1 paket yükseltilmeyecek.
>   35 paket tam olarak kurulmayacak ya da kaldırılmayacak.
>   7.220 kB arşiv dosyası indirilecek.
>   Bu işlem tamamlandıktan sonra 127 MB ek disk alanı kullanılacak.
>   Devam etmek istiyor musunuz? [E/h] e
>   İndir: 1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main i386 libc6 i386 2.23-0ubuntu3 [2.270 kB]
>   İndir: 2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main i386 libgl1-mesa-dri i386 11.2.0-1ubuntu2 [4.950 kB]
>   24 sn.'de 7.220 kB alındı (300 kB/s)
>   N: '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' dizinindeki 'opera-stable.list.save' dosyası geçersiz bir dosya uzantısı olduğu için yok sayılıyor
>   N: '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' dizinindeki 'steam.list.save' dosyası geçersiz bir dosya uzantısı olduğu için yok sayılıyor
>   N: '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' dizinindeki 'ubuntu-wine-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list.save' dosyası geçersiz bir dosya uzantısı olduğu için yok sayılıyor
>   N: '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' dizinindeki 'spotify.list.save' dosyası geçersiz bir dosya uzantısı olduğu için yok sayılıyor
>   Paketler önyapılandırılıyor ...
>   (Veritabanı okunuyor ... 185674 dosya veya dizin kurulu durumda.)
>   Paket açılacak: .../libc6_2.23-0ubuntu3_i386.deb ...
>   Paket açılıyor: libc6:i386 (2.23-0ubuntu3) ...
>   dpkg: /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.23-0ubuntu3_i386.deb arşivi işlenirken sorun yaşandı (--unpack):
>    paylaşılan '/usr/share/lintian/overrides/libc6' dosyasının üzerine yazılmaya çalışılıyor, dosya libc6:i386 paketinin diğer örneklerinden farklı
>   Paket açılacak: .../libgl1-mesa-dri_11.2.0-1ubuntu2_i386.deb ...
>   Paket açılıyor: libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 (11.2.0-1ubuntu2) ...
>   dpkg: /var/cache/apt/archives/libgl1-mesa-dri_11.2.0-1ubuntu2_i386.deb arşivi işlenirken sorun yaşandı (--unpack):
>    paylaşılan '/usr/share/doc/libgl1-mesa-dri/copyright' dosyasının üzerine yazılmaya çalışılıyor, dosya libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 paketinin diğer örneklerinden farklı
>   Tetikleyiciler işleniyor: libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu3) ...
>   İşleme sırasında hatalarla karşılaşıldı:
>    /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.23-0ubuntu3_i386.deb
>    /var/cache/apt/archives/libgl1-mesa-dri_11.2.0-1ubuntu2_i386.deb
>   N: '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' dizinindeki 'opera-stable.list.save' dosyası geçersiz bir dosya uzantısı olduğu için yok sayılıyor
>   N: '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' dizinindeki 'steam.list.save' dosyası geçersiz bir dosya uzantısı olduğu için yok sayılıyor
>   N: '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' dizinindeki 'ubuntu-wine-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list.save' dosyası geçersiz bir dosya uzantısı olduğu için yok sayılıyor
>   N: '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' dizinindeki 'spotify.list.save' dosyası geçersiz bir dosya uzantısı olduğu için yok sayılıyor
>   E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

PS: I only installed f.lux indicator, Opera browser and spottily client after fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04.

**EDIT:** By the way, all my dependenciy problems are relevant to i386. I checked if I enabled `multiarch` or not, it seems like I've enabled it.

**EDIT:** Now I tried to let Steam update itself first, and then install those dependencies. This time it downloaded them and with some errors installed them. But they all are broken of course. So nothing changed.

**FINAL EDIT:** After a fresh installation of Ubuntu 16.04, and installing proper upgrades before any app, my problem solved. I can again install i386 libraries.

Comment: As currently written, your terminal output is hard to understand. You should export the `LANG` variable with `export LANG=C` before issuing commands that you want to show here. Moreover, your "final edit" should be posted as a self-answer.

Answer (score 1):

So you did `apt-get update`? Please check that you have sources in /etc/apt/sources.list

```
###### Ubuntu Main Repos
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted universe multiverse 
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted universe multiverse 

###### Ubuntu Update Repos
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse 
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse 
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse
```

If it's so sad:

> every time there is a missing dependency and now I don't have my basic apps

I think you should remove unmet dependencies. When you try to install a new thing there will be unmet dependencies - remove them, and try install those package.

PS:

`apt-get autoremove -y`

Comment: Yes, I did that too, and now even opened the list with gedit to make sure that I have them in the list. And unfortunately I have them. However I was using turkey server, can that be a problem?

Comment: When I do that it doesn't do anything know and still can't install anything. But when I use that command, there is always some packages that "won't be updated"?

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove .save files

```
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d
/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ ls
```

and remove all 
with this

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ sudo rm opera-stable.list.save
/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ sudo rm steam.list.save
/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ sudo rm ubuntu-wine-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list.save
/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ sudo rm spotify.list.save
```

Rastgele.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using Xubuntu but since they both rely on same repositories, the solution will probably be the same.

Firstly, the reason for this problem is the out-dated configuration of the Ubuntu Turkish repo servers. After trying a handful of solutions, I've edited the repo sources and finally I can install Steam in peace. Maybe this is the exact reason why there isn't any fuss about this issue since the US Servers are up-to-date.

Warning: Before proceeding to the solution, I've noticed that you've mentioned something about "losing basic apps" and this may indicate that you've removed some of the core libraries while trying to solve dependency issues. I highly suggest that you do a clean reinstall of the Ubuntu.

Now, to the solution:

1) Edit the sources list as

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

2) Delete the "tr." from all urls

For example change this:

```
deb http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
```

Into this:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
```

3) Save the list with

```
Ctrl + O
```

4) Do a fully update/upgrade routine

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade && sudo apt-get autoremove
```

5) Finally, install Steam by using the repositories

```
sudo apt-get install steam
```

Thats it! Well, at least for me!

Comment: Well thanks for your help, but it didn't work either. By the way when I said I don't have basic apps I meant skype, steam etc. They're my basic apps. :)

Comment: Hmm, could you update your question with corresponding terminal outputs please? What does it say when you try to install those apps from the terminal?